# How to show a Grouped product in a CMS page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customization, magento2.4

Good Day

I would like to place a Grouped product in a CMS page, the info view where you can see each releted product and can change the qty and add to cart.

I have tried to use a block directive (I ope thats the correct terminology) that i have attempted to create with no success.

Ideally i would like to add the block by using this type of format:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="BlockName" product_id="1" template="Magento_Theme::groupedproduct.phtml"}}
```

That way i could add to any page or even add multiple products to a page.

Can this be done or is there an extension that could do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can add group product from phtml using above method. Do you want show single product or multiple products in CMS page ?